# Media Monkey music management alternative?

Tags: software-recommendation, music

Media Monkey has some great and simple music management tools, like batch renaming, moving, fetching meta-data, etc.

I use Picard for some music organisation, but it doesn't have as many options, namely that it will only automatically rename music it finds in its database.

I have a lot of classical music which isn't in any data base or is already named how I want it (in their file-names) and I want to write the correct meta data and organise these files into folders.

So is there other music management applications in Linux other than Picard with a similar feature set to Media Monkey?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Ex Falso, part of [Quod Libet](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/)? (disclaimer: I'm one of the devs).

It's optimised for tag-obsessives and classical music, where tagging is a lot more complex. Though it works best on its own library (easily set up), you can still use the File System Browser with the tag editor to re-tag, rename, or number any of your files on disk:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As to music organizer for Linux, have you tried [Banshee](http://banshee-project.org/)?
This list is about [music organizing freeware](http://imelfin.com/best-free-music-organizer-software-review-download.html), covering several linux-supported freeware as well.

Comment: It is preferable if a summary is posted here, and the link provided for further reference. Answers with just links are not encouraged on Ask Ubuntu.